# How to have the Resource file containing messages,strings for each language in .NET 4.5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, localization, globalization

I have to a Resource files for Arabic and Spanish languages containing Error messages,dialog messages and some strings which will be used in the code behind.Now I want to access the related language resource file to read the strings as per the user selected culture.

Can any one help me regarding this ?

Answer (score 0):

In `web.config` set

```
<system.web>
<globalization uiCulture="en" />
</system.web>
```

At very first uiCulture is `en`.

In `ASPX` file you may use ddl like following:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="cboLanguage" runat="server" CssClass="combobox"
Width="150px" meta:resourcekey="cboLanguageResource1">
<asp:ListItem meta:resourceKey="ListItemLanguageResource1" Text="English" Value="en"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem meta:resourceKey="ListItemLanguageResource5" Text="French" Value="fr"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem meta:resourceKey="ListItemLanguageResource4" Text="German" Value="de"></asp:ListItem>    
<asp:ListItem meta:resourceKey="ListItemLanguageResource3" Text="Italian" Value="it"></asp:ListItem>                                                    
<asp:ListItem meta:resourceKey="ListItemLanguageResource2" Text="Portuguese" Value="pt"></asp:ListItem>                                                                                                                                                                        
<asp:ListItem meta:resourceKey="ListItemLanguageResource6" Text="Spanish" Value="es"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:Button ID="btnLanguage" runat="server" Text="Update" CssClass="button"
                                                        meta:resourcekey="btnLanguageResource1" OnClick="btnLanguage_Click" />
```

In `Code Behind` set the `uiCulture` at `btnLanguage_Click`

```
protected void btnLanguage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Configuration Config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
        GlobalizationSection section = (GlobalizationSection)Config.GetSection("system.web/globalization");
        section.UICulture = cboLanguage.SelectedValue.ToString();
        Config.Save();
        Response.Redirect("Defaults.aspx", false);
    }
```

In code behind while showing error messages do this:-

`Label1.Text =  GetLocalResourceObject("Key").ToString();`

In resource file

```
String | Value
Key | Record has been Saved.
```

Comment: For example , I have added a record and in English we show as "Record created successfully!" and in Arabic we need to show the Arabic text.We need to read the arabic text based on the current culture i.e., Arabic.

Comment: @Hemant Kumar above suggesio will change uiCulture to the selected language now are you asking for how to show the messages from the resource file ?

Comment: In code behind you can also get the local resource object like this  `GetLocalResourceObject("key").ToString();` @Hemant Kumar

Comment: My Application is Web Application.How can I do this in Web Applications ?

Comment: @Hemant Kumar. This is for Web Application. Did you try this sir?